# XML Lint parser error on a character

Tags: xml, unix

I have a XML generated from a java program.

However, the output in the file is in a single line and hence unreadable.

Thus, I am using xmllint as below to format the xml:

```
xmllint --format $MY_DIR/source.xml > $MY_DIR/destination.xml
```

This is resulting in a parser error as below:

```
parser error : internal error Firm'
```

The character present on that word seems to be a special character which xmllint is unable to handle.

On checking the data on microsoft word, the character is as below:

[image: Special Character]

How can I handle this character in xmllint?

Is there any other command present in unix other than xmllint to format the xml to human readable form and which may support these characters in the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the source XML document is your only option.